# Raspberry pi shows black screen for the desktop

Tags: hardware, sd-card, display

Though the terminal works fine, whenever i start the desktop(either with startx or booting to the desktop), I get a black screen with just my mouse. I can do ctl+alt+f6, and i can still right click, which shows the options terminal emulator, web browser, Desktops, obconf, reconfigure , restart, and exit. Whenever i press any of these though, i'm not sure anything happens. Before this problem, i didn't change any config files, I was just working on a python project. Then the next time i turned it on, my problem occurred out of now where. Can anyone give me a solution on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

> Then the next time i turned it on, my problem occurred out of now where.

Ah, but **how** did you turn it off?  This sounds like damage/corruption to the files used by the window manager or some session related software that is a client to the X Server (which is providing the base, black {unless you use the `-retro` or `-wr`option when it is started!} screen and mouse as it is supposed to.)  Given that you have not been messing in that area I have a hunch that perhaps you did not wait long enough after issuing the `shutdown` (or clicked the corresponding GUI option) before removing power from the Pi. {You DID use a shutdown process I hope, you must not just "pull the plug"!}

As a somewhat imprecise approach if you can identify which "packages" might be providing the bit that isn't working you can reinstall them using `sudo aptitude --reinstall install {packagename}`<sup>*Edited to insert the* "--" *and* "install" *that are needed!*</sup> where you replace `{packagename}` with what you need to fix; *if you include an `-s` between `aptitude` and `--reinstall` it will just tell you what it would do without actually doing it*.

My difficulty in advising you is that I don't have a Pi up and running at the moment to look for possible candidates to check.  I suppose it might be worth looking through the contents of various log files to find issues in `/var/log/`, you might possibly pay special attention to any of these if you have them: `xdm.log`, `user.log`, `syslog` oh, and also `.xsession-errors` in your home directory (the leading `.` means it is a "hidden" file and won't show up in `ls` output unless you include an `a` in the options, e.g. use `ls ~la ~` to see the contents of your home directory to hunt for that last file.